# How do I set a fleet to orbit a planet?

Tags: stellaris

If I click on my fleet, and the right click a planet I own - they will just move there (I get no menu pop up, they just move there).  Once they have reached the planet they will go into sleep/inactive mode.

If I click to repair or upgrade my fleet, they will go get repaired/upgraded, and then they will be orbiting a planet (which costs me less energy).

Also if my fleet gets lost in space (eg. I do an emergency retreat from combat), when they re-appear around a planet they are orbiting that planet.

If I select an army in a transport ship, and then right click a planet, I get a menu with the options to enter orbit or land armies.

---

Basically I just want to be able to tell my fleet to orbit a planet at any time (not just when I am upgrading or repairing my fleet).

Is this possible? I am guessing I am just missing something obvious, but I cant find how to do this anywhere...

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot?  That might help shed some light on why your ships won't orbit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No you're doing it right.**

You just have to **right click on a planet you own** to have it orbit. If you have modules like Crew Quarters or Engineering Bays then it will reduce the cost further.

I'd check again to make sure because it really is just as simple as right clicking a planet you own - if you don't own it you won't get the reduced cost.

The reason transport ships have the option when you right click is because they can land on planets unlike your military fleet.

Fuller: Right clicking on the system will just move it straight to the system. If you go into the system, go to the planet *that you own*, and while your fleet is selected, **right click on the green bar with the planet's name**, your fleet should travel there and enter orbit. 
 You can confirm this by looking at the fleet and near the Admiral it should say: "Orbiting 'Planet Name'", also your income should go up as maintenance is lower for being in a planet's orbit (**with a space station**).

Comment: this just isn't working for me - I click on my fleet, and right click on a planet (or on a system in the galaxy map) and my fleet just moves there... it never enters into orbit - if this is automatic, then I must be being stupid and missing something fairly basic - could you please explain the process of getting a fleet to orbit a planet in real basic terms, like you were speaking to a witless child :)

Comment: @Jimmery I added a fuller explanation to the answer

Comment: thanks man - turns out I was being a dumb ass after all - I wasn't clicking on the planets themselves - thanks for the help - have a tick

Answer (score 2):

Right click the **space station**, not the planet.

Technically it is the space station with its modules what reduces the maintenance cost. This also explains why the ships entered the low-maintenance mode after upgrading or healing.

Comment: Would that mean that a planet without a spaceport doesn't lower energy costs for orbiting fleets?